# Round Robin Qualification

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

There are 10 teams and the top 4 go through. Teams play each other once, and may only win or lose. What is the minimum number of wins with which a team could possibly go through? What is the maximum number of wins with which a team would still be eliminated.

What about for 20 teams and top 8 going through?

For the first part, I wanted maximize points between the top 3 teams, so I gave them 9,8,7 wins, leaving (45-24)=21 wins to be distributed between the bottom 7. Hence 3 points each and one of these would qualify.

For the second part, I had a similar approach, instead minimizing points for bottom 5 teams, and then splitting the remaining.

Comment: "Hence 3 points each and one of these would qualify." So some sort of random selection is being allowed if a group with same number of wins is to qualify/be eliminated ?

Comment: Yes, a random selection is allowed.

Comment: I have accounted for that in the answer

Answer (score 1):

*Help for first problem*

Taking 1 point for win, 0 points for loss, $\binom{10}2$ matches will have $45$ points at stake

For the highest non-selection score, rank the teams into uniquely from best to worst.

The highest non-selection score can be $5$ with  monotonically decreasing scores, viz
$9-8-7-6-\fbox5-4-3-2-1-0$

This will be a *unique* highest score for *non-selection.*

The lowest *selection score* has already been computed by you correctly as $3$, (there will be many with the same score, selction by lottery.)\

---

Work out for  "20 teams and top 8 going through" in similar fashion

Comment: Is the answer clear ?